# how to integrate custom two factor authentication with Outlook Web Access exchange?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exchange-server, outlook-web-app, two-factor-authentication

i'm building a custom two factor authentication component for my company using asp.net MVC,  and i want to integrate it with Microsoft Exchange Outlook Web Access s o how i can do that ? can i add extra text box for OWA login page ?